# Unexpected substitution for & with sed

Tags: shell, csv, utf-8, sed

I have a CSV file containing some special characters and their HTML entity names

ex: `htm.csv`

```
À,&Agrave;
Á,&Aacute;
Â,&Acirc;
Ã,&Atilde;
É,&Eacute;
Ê,&Ecirc;
Í,&Iacute;
Ó,&Oacute;
Ô,&Ocirc;
Õ,&Otilde;
```

and I have a number of `.php` files where these special characters are present. I have written a shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=","
while read orig html
do
   for fl in *.php; do
   mv $fl $fl.old
   sed 's/'$orig'/'$html'/g' $fl.old > $fl
   done
done< "htm.csv"
```

but the problem is when using the contents of `$html`, it is printing the contents of `$orig` instead of `"&"`.

Answer (score 5):

`&` is a special character meaning "the whole matched string" in the `s///` command. Use `\&`.

Comment: using \\& its working but for a bunch of file its not working

Comment: for documentation of that, see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)

Comment: "To include a literal \, &, or newline in the final replacement, be sure to precede the desired \, &, or newline in the replacement with a \."

Comment: Note that sed has to see '`\&`'.  You have to get that backslash past the shell, which greatly complicates things.

Answer (score 1):

Use any character as a command delimiter, here is an example:

```
sed -Ei "s|$k|$j|g" filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the special characters you can also make the commands a bit safer and shorter:

- There's no need for `mv` if your `sed` supports `-i` (in-place replacement)
- To avoid setting `IFS` for the rest of the commands you can limit its scope
- Escape `&` in `$html`

The result:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS="," read orig html
do
    for fl in *.php
    do
        sed -i 's/'$orig'/'${html//&/\\&}'/g' "$fl"
    done
done < "htm.csv"
```

Please add an example if it doesn't work for you. There could be other special characters which would have to be escaped.