# How to sed replace UTF-8 characters with HTML entities in another file?

Tags: sed

I'm running `cygwin` under `windows 10`

Have a dictionary file (`1-dictionary.txt`) that looks like this:

```
labelling   labeling
flavour flavor
colour  color
organisations   organizations
végétales   v&#x00E9;g&#x00E9;tales
contr?lée   contr&#x00F4;l&#x00E9;e
"   &#x0022;
```

The separators between are `TAB`s (`\t`s).

The dictionary file is encoded as `UTF-8`.

Want to replace words and symbols in the first column with words and HTML entities in the second column.

My source file (`2-source.txt`) has the target UTF-8 and ASCII symbols. The source file also is encoded as `UTF-8`.

Sample text looks like this:

```
Cultivar was coined by Bailey and it is generally regarded as a portmanteau of "cultivated" and "variety" ... The International Union for the Protection of New Varieties of Plants (UPOV - French: Union internationale pour la protection des obtentions végétales) offers legal protection of plant cultivars ...Terroir is the basis of the French wine appellation d'origine contrôlée (AOC) system
```

I run the following `sed` one-liner in a shell script (./3-script.sh):

`sed -f <(sed -E 's_(.+)\t(.+)_s/\1/\2/g_' 1-dictionary.txt) 2-source.txt > 3-translation.txt`

The substitution of English (en-GB) words with American (en-US) words in `3-translation.txt` is successful.

However the substitution of ASCII symbols, such as the quote symbol, and UTF-8 words produces this result:

```
vvégétales#x00E9;gvégétales#x00E9;tales)
contrcontrôlée#x00F4;lcontrôlée#x00E9;e (AOC)
```

If i use only the specific symbol (not the full word) I get results like this:

```
vé#x00E9;gé#x00E9;tales
"#x0022cultivated"#x0022
contrô#x00F4;lé#x00E9;e
```

The ASCII quote symbol is appended with `&#x0022;` - it is not replaced.

Similarly, the UTF-8 symbol is appended with its HTML entity - not replaced with the HTML entity.

The expected output would look like this:

```
v#x00E9;g#x00E9;tales
#x0022cultivated#x0022
contr#x00F4;l#x00E9;e
```

How to modify the `sed` script so that target ASCII and UTF-8 symbols are replaced with their HTML entity equivalent as defined in the dictionary file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected substitution for & with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200249/unexpected-substitution-for-with-sed)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern

Comment: I tried it, just replace all `&` with `\&` in your `1-dictionary.txt` will solve your problem. Try it, see if it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it, just replace all `&` with `\&` in your `1-dictionary.txt` will solve your problem.

Sed's substitute uses a [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) as the *from* part, so when you use it like that, notice those regex characters and add `\` to prepare them to be [escaped](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Escapes.html#Escapes).

And the *to* part will have special characters too, mainly `\` and `&`, add extra `\` to prepare them to be [escaped](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) too.

Above linked to [GNU sed's document](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents), for other `sed` version, you can also check `man sed`.